# How to connect to Firebird with Node.js when wire encryption is enabled?

Tags: node.js, firebird, node-firebird

I'm trying to connect to a Firebird server with Node.js "node-firebird", but I always get the error

> Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server at
> doCallback

The problem is that I'm just trying to connect on a server that a company gave me the data to connect, however I don't have access to change the wire crypt in this Firebird server, neither they know how to do that.

Could someone give me the leads to show them what to do and make it works? Or if you have any suggestions on how to change on my JS any data to be able to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to disable the wirecrypt setting of Firebird is documented in the [node-firebird documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firebird) under "Firebird 3.0 Support" (though personally, I would recommend changing `WireCrypt` to `Enabled` instead of `Disabled` (the default is `Required`), so clients that do support wire protocol encryption can still encrypt their connection.

In short:

1. Open firebird.conf
2. See if `WireCrypt` is already configured, and add or modify it to `WireCrypt = Enabled` (lines prefixed with `#` are comments)
3. Restart Firebird

Be careful with applying the other settings as suggested in the node-firebird documentation, as that might cause problems for other applications connecting to the Firebird server. For example, instead of the suggested `UserManager = Legacy_UserManager`, use `UserManager = Srp, Legacy_UserManager`.

Alternatively, switch to another Node.js library for Firebird. The ones using fbclient/libfbclient will support encryption if you're using a Firebird 3.0 or higher client library. For example, [node-firebird-driver-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firebird-driver-native). Given the documentation of the library is lacking, maybe you'll find [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mariuz/87266d930917114c276f64985a054849) helpful.

In case you're using Firebird 4.0 or higher, also look at [Error: Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server - trying to connect node server with Firebird 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78240701/error-incompatible-wire-encryption-levels-requested-on-client-and-server-tryi).

Comment: Hello, Mark! Thanks for the answer!
Is this firebird.conf a configuration that I can change on the server? This Server is hosted on another company, so I can just ask the IT from this company to change this firebird.conf?
This "node-firebird-driver-native", I couldn't find how to connect on it...

Comment: `firebird.conf` file is the configuration of Firebird server, on Windows it is in the installation directory of the Firebird server. On Linux it depends on the distribution and the Firebird package you used.

Comment: OK, I'm going to give it a try, I'm in th meanwhile trying to make `node-firebird-driver-native` to work, but that's being kinda complicated, I can't manage to connect to the database... Would you have any hints on it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I don't program in Node.js myself, but looking at the documentation, I can understand why you're having problems using it, it doesn't explain things at all.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe this gist can help you: https://gist.github.com/mariuz/87266d930917114c276f64985a054849

Comment: Omg, it seems that it's working, I'm just going to test a little bit more.. if it works I'll mark it as correct! Thanks a lot

Comment: Mark, that worked perfectly! How do I select it as an answer? The link you said in the comments? I'm just facing one single error, on my electron, when I have this firebird funciton being called, I face the error "DevTools was diconnect from this page"

Comment: @Kevin I added the link into my answer. You can accept it by ticking the checkmark in front of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `firebird.conf` add `WireCrypt = Enabled`