# Error: Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server - trying to connect node server with Firebird 4.0

Tags: node.js, firebird, node-firebird, firebird-4.0

I'm attempting to establish a connection, but I'm encountering an error. Despite thorough research and exploring various solutions, none have been effective for me, including toggling the WireCrypt setting between enabled and disabled in the `firebird.conf` file. I've also tested this with Firebird 5.0, but the issue persists. Yes, I restarted both the server and my PC.

Please note: using Firebird 3.0 or earlier versions is **not** an option for me.

My code:

```
const firebird = require('node-firebird');

const options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3050,
    database: 'C:\\Vetor\\INTEGRACAO\\BANCO\\5175_REALIZA_JURANDIR.FDB',
    user: 'SYSDBA',
    password: 'SySkatrog',
    lowercase_keys: false, 
    role: null, 
    pageSize: 4096, 
    retryConnectionInterval: 1000, // reconnect interval in case of connection drop
    blobAsText: false, // set to true to get blob as text, only affects blob subtype 1
    encoding: 'UTF-8'
};

firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that node-firebird reports the error *"Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server"* also when there is a mismatch between authentication plugins tried by the client and expected by the server, and not just when it can't establish a connection because the server has `WireCrypt` set to `Required` (the default).

The node-firebird driver implements the `Srp` authentication, but though Firebird 4.0 and 5.0 still support it, they default to only accepting `Srp256` authentication, which the node-firebird doesn't attempt, and as a result, the connection is rejected. The node-firebird driver then incorrectly assumes this was due to the encryption level and reports the wrong error.

To fix this, you need to make two changes to your `firebird.conf`:

1. Set `WireCrypt = Enabled` (don't use `Disabled`, as that will also disable encryption for drivers that do support it)
2. Set `AuthClient = Srp256, Srp` (`Srp` is less secure than `Srp256`, so it should be tried *after* `Srp256`)

After making these changes, restart the Firebird server, and your Node.js application should now be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things,
First was to remove the separation of client and server and put them both in just one variable.
Second, I followed Mark Rotteveel's suggestion, but I didn't set `AuthClient = Srp256, Srp` as he said, I had to set `AuthClient = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi`.

Anyway, he helped me.